# Download third party app apple store. Reject apple submission?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an application that requires Google Chrome to work. So I check if Chrome is installed using `canOpenURL` with URL scheme of Chrome. If it's not installed, tell user it's required to install.

So is this a reason to reject for Apple submission? When download the app, use the URL scheme to access the Apple store so I don't download any binary, I request this action to OS.

Comment: Can you add the Apple's response please.

Comment: kindly share apples response along with rejection reason or code

Comment: @KenanKarakecili, no I don't submit anything yet. Only want to ask if this there a reason to Apple rejects the app

Comment: Apple won't reject if you app asks to download another app. Do you need any other help relating to this?

Comment: @KenanKarakecili, but you can obligate download the app?

Comment: You can find a workaround. One example is to show an alert unless that app is installed. If user comes back to your app without downloading the other app, you'll show an alert again.

Comment: @KenanKarakecili yeah, great idea. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I passed the solution to the answer. If my solution worked, please select it as the selected answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple won't reject if you app asks to download another app.

If you want the other app required to be installed, you can find a custom workaround.

One example is to show an alert unless that app is installed. If user comes back to your app without downloading the other app, you'll show an alert again.